# CakePHP admin and website router

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I'm learning CakePHP and I'm building a CMS, but I cant seem to get my router right.

Every url should use the index action of the WebsiteController, except "admin"

/admin works, but when I go to /foobar it asks for FoobarController

```
Router::connect("/admin/:controller/:action", 
    array("controller" => "admin")
);
Router::connect("/", 
    array("controller" => "website", "action" => "index")
);
Router::connect("/:slug/*", 
    array("controller" => "website", "action" => "index"), 
    array("pass" => array("slug"), "slug" => '(?!admin)')
);
```

Comment: I've edited the question, /admin works, the rest doesn't

Comment: Why do you need an admin controller? It is IMHO better for multiple reasons to go for prefixed routing and keep the code in context, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing.

Comment: I am, admin is the dashboard. The rest is all With prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out.

By removing:

```
Router::connect("/admin/:action",
    array("controller" => "admin")
);
Router::connect("/",
    array("controller" => "website", "action" => "index")
);
```

And adding:

```
Router::connect("/admin",
    array("controller" => "admin", "action" => "index")
);

Router::connect("/:slug",
    array("controller" => "website", "action" => "index"),
    array("pass" => array("slug"))
);
```

Special thanks to [PGBI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3992478/pgbi)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `"slug" => '(?!admin)'`. You don't need it anyway because an url starting with /admin will already be caught by your first route.

Other problem, the following route does not make sense:

```
Router::connect("/admin/:controller/:action", 
   array("controller" => "admin")
);`
```

It basically tells to handle /admin/foobar url by admin Controller and also foobar Controller.

Try this:

```
Router::connect("/admin",
    array("controller" => "admin", "action" => "index")
);
Router::connect("/admin/:action",
    array("controller" => "admin")
);
Router::connect("/",
    array("controller" => "website", "action" => "index")
);
Router::connect("/:slug/*",
    array("controller" => "website", "action" => "index"),
    array("pass" => array("slug"))
);
```

Comment: When I try this, /admin will also go to website index()

Comment: Yeah, I answered too quickly. I edited my answer, hope it works better.

Comment: The code did work, but /admin/pages (Pages is a controller) now shows the page as it were a page of the website

Comment: In your question, you do not describe what should handle "/admin/foobar". I assumed the answer would be controller => admin, action => foobar.

Comment: Instead of using an "admin" controller it would be better to use prefixed admin_ actions to keep the code in context. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing